# How to schedule email whit req.body and node-cron

Tags: node.js, nodemailer, node-cron

i need to schedule email send, i'm using node-cron.
i want to know how to use "req.body" for date and time to schedule.

[image: This is the code]

i need help to resolve how insert in this part of code the req.body

```
cron.schedule('* * * * *')
```

and if useful to use

```
<input type="time">
<input type="date">
```

Thanks for all

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
Please add the code directly as code in your question, not as picture. That helps others to answer faster and easier. [Here is still a general guid for asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks!

Comment: embedded picture, but it's always preferable to have it as text as it enables others to copy and paste for answers.

Comment: If I am not wrong req.body works on names so you need to have “ name “ attribute added to your inputs

Answer (score 0):

Since the node cron expression is string you can pass the variables in form of string 
something like

```
let c="0";
cron.schedule(`${c} * * * * *`, ()=>{ // you can use template literals to pass variable args
// your job runs every minute

})
```

Like wise you can pass different arguments  according to your requirements.
You can refer official documentation of node cron here-https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron